# Qt5 embedded window stays independent and isn't being displayed in my own

Tags: c++, qt5, x11

I've been trying to learn how to embed a window in Qt5 for my game engine. I'm getting the window id from `xwininfo`. It's valid, `fromWinId` doesn't return `nullptr`. The app runs with no errors, but the window doesn't show anything and the embedded one stays independent of my window.

There is some of the background leaking through my window.
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eFic.png) (The window leaking through IS NOT the one I'm trying to embed)

This is my code, I am compiling with Clang 11 and Qt 5.15.1 and running on Debian with X11.

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QWindow>
#include <iostream>

class main_window : public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit main_window(const uint32_t wid)
    {
        QWindow* window = QWindow::fromWinId((WId)wid);
        window->setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

        QWidget* widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window);
        widget->setParent(this);

        auto* layout = new QGridLayout{};
        layout->addWidget(widget);
        setLayout(layout);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** const argv)
{
    QApplication app{argc, argv};

    uint32_t wid;
    std::cin >> wid;

    main_window window{wid};
    window.show();

    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works for me (GCC 10.2.0, Qt 5.15.1, Gentoo Linux). Are you sure you are passing the correct window ID on stdin?

Comment: @jotik Yes, because when I pass a random ID there are lots of xcb errors, and when I pass this there are none. Do you think this might be an issue with my debian install?

Comment: I don't know. You could try to embed some other windows, personally I only tried embedding a KCalc (from Qt based KDE) window after using `xwininfo` to get its ID, and then had to resize the parent window for the embedded window to display inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the fix was to pass the window id as a decimal, not hex value. It is weird though, because there weren't any errors.